# Testing a python script with pytest - permission issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

I have unit tested my modules using pytest without issue. I would also like to test my script (which imports some of the modules), but I am getting a permission error. I am new to writing larger python projects that actually need to be tested and maintained, so my directory structure may be non-optimal, so please let me know if that is the case. My directory structure looks like -

```
parent
 modules
  __init__.py
  module1.py
  ...
 test
  ...
  test_script.py
 script.py
```

My test code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import train

def test_train_dataset1():
  #run the script
  p = subprocess.Popen(['./train.py', 'test_models', 'test1', 'data/temp.json', '--isfile'])
  #more code to check output
```

My error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './train.py'
```

Comment: are using any UNIX system?

Comment: I'm on a max OS X

Comment: Change to `p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'train.py', 'test_models` ...`

Answer (score 1):

`Permission denied: './train.py'` is most certainly mean the file is not executable. To fix:

```
chmod a+x ./train.py
```

Also verify it has a proper shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/python` or such).

PS. When you do `import train` do you import from the same `train.py`? If not — you shouldn't give the script the same name as a module/package you're gonna import.